# How to Call the Tuple in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, tuples

```
 public Tuple<string, int> aaCreeDtaOneAccount(int NbLines, string Straccref)
 {
     return new Tuple<string,int>(StrFullFilDtaname,NbLines);
 }
```

**This function is in my Business Layer and i want to access in my UI**

I want to access the two values NbLines and StrFullFilDtaname

How do i do that in C# Please Help

Comment: `aaCreeDta`  ? There's no extra charge for more characters in your method names. Full meaningful names are your friend and future you will thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Item1` and `Item2` properties of [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) class:

```
var tuple = aaCreeDtaOneAccount(42, "Foo");
var strFullFitDtaname = tuple.Item1;
var nblines = tuple.Item2;
```